# AcceptSocket does not respect a Thread.Abort request

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

My understanding is that Thread.Abort should raise a ThreadAbortException on a blocked thread, however this does not seem to be the case when dealing with `TcpListener.AcceptSocket`.  Here's the most basic illustration of the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Listen);
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // give it a second to get going
        Console.WriteLine("Aborting listener thread");
        thread.Abort();
        thread.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Listener thread finished press <enter> to end app.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting to listen");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4070);
            listener.Start();
            Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            return;
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Abort requested");
        }
    }
}
```

The `thread.Abort()` call should stop the `AcceptSocket` and execute the `ThreadAbortException` handler.  Howerver this does not happen.

Swapping out my Listen wrapper of `AcceptSocket` for ListenAsync which calls `BeginAcceptSocket` instead:

```
static void ListenAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            ManualResetEvent clientConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            Console.WriteLine("Starting to listen");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4070);
            listener.Start();
            clientConnected.Reset();
            var iasyncResult = listener.BeginAcceptSocket((ar) =>
            {
                Socket socket = listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                clientConnected.Set();
            }, null);
            clientConnected.WaitOne();

            return;
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Abort requested");
        }
    }
```

In this case it "appears" to work fine.  The ThreadAbortException is caught while the thread is doing a WaitOne.  HOWEVER the thread that was created by the call to BeginAcceptSocket is still running and able to accept a socket (I verified this by opening that port with Telnet)

Finally, I added `Listener.Stop` as part of the `TheadAbortException` handler, and a try catch around the EndAcceptSocket call (since the socket is disposed by the Stop)

Is this really the best approach starting and stopping the process of listening for socket connections?

Comment: What happens with the clientConnected event when you kill the thread? Why aren't you disposing of objects? What do you do with the socket once accepted?

Comment: Using `Thread.Abort` is almost always a dirty hack and should be avoided. Let your threads terminate gracefully... don't pull the rug from under them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that `Thread.Abort` doesn't abort a thread that's listening on a socket is because that thread is blocked inside (the moral equivalent of) a `listen()` kernel call. The `ThreadAbortException` can only be raised by the CLR when the CLR is actually executing, and during a call to `listen` thread is actually stuck inside an unmanaged system call. Once the call to `listen` returns and the execution resumes inside the CLR, the thread abortion can be continued.

I second the advice not to use `Thread.Abort()`. If you do decide to go that route, you can use a technique similar to the one in your second example. However, you'd be better off using a different method and simply calling `Listener.Stop()` when you want to shut down the thread listener.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with Thead.Abort(), however I'm happy to heed the advice and will investigate other options.

Comment: @Ralph: From a broad perspective, `Thread.Abort` has issues because: a) (as you see here), it gives the false perception that the target thread will immediately (or even *soon*) be aborted, but the CLR is at the mercy of unmanaged code, and b) it is destructive and there is no telling what state the thread will be in when it's aborted. It's strongly recommended that you instead use a cancellation/abort flag of some kind and use blocking methods with timeouts when possible. This way you can check your cancellation flag and do whatever cleanup (if any) that's appropriate at the time.