# how to close a thread containing a blocking method in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, blocking, terminate

I create a thread to handle a blocking method in my code.  this way, my code can do other things beside running that blocking method.

question:  how can I terminate the thread properly?  do I have to unblock the blocking method, then terminate the thread.  or can I just terminate the thread without worrying about any ugly crashing?

Comment: If you don't want the thread to block forever, don't code it to. It really is that simple. Any time you feel like you need to reach in from the outside and force a thread to do something, that just proves you didn't code the thread to do what you really wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Call `yourthread.Abort()`. It's not like in the old days where this would cause you to break everything when resources and locks weren't released, now this causes quite a nice exception to be raised that can be handled in the normal way...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx

When I say "the normal way" it seems that thread abort exception auto re-raises (quite a nice trick)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

but that wouldn't stop you being a douche and kicking off another big thing in the catch block...

Comment: MSDN says that Abort() 'usually terminates the thread'.  is there a guaranteed way to shut it down?  =/

Comment: actually, a little experimenting and that's not quite so simple - the exception seem to propagate even when handled... (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx)

Comment: Ahh, good old `Thread.Abort`...burning your house down to kill that spider you saw...

Comment: Actually it is not guaranteed. The thread may not see the exception at all. There's a long list of exceptions in the Remarks section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options.  If you don't care if the operation completes when the application is going down you might be better off using a ThreadPool thread via [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx)  or (as Servy suggests in comments) set the [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property of your thread to true, which will allow the process to exit without the thread exiting.

If you do care about the operation completing and/or have cleanup logic that needs to be run on shutdown you probably don't really want to use Thread.Abort, at least not as your goto strategy.  What I use is something similar to this:

```
public abstract class DisposableThread : IDisposable
{
    private ManualResetEvent exiting = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Thread theThread;
    private  TimeSpan abortTimeout;

    public DisposableThread():
        this(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    {
    }

    public DisposableThread(TimeSpan abortTimeout)
    {
        this.abortTimeout = abortTimeout;
        theThread = new Thread((_) => ThreadProc());
    }

    protected virtual void ThreadProc()
    {
        while(!exiting.WaitOne(0))
        {
            WorkUnit(exiting);
        }
        ThreadCleanup();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        exiting.Set();
        if (!theThread.Join(abortTimeout))
        {
            // logme -- the thread didn't shutdown gracefully
            theThread.Abort();
            while (!theThread.Join(1000))
            {
                // logme -- the thread is doing something dumb in an exception handler
            }
        }
        exiting.Dispose();
    }

    // WorkUnit should return as quickly as safe if the exiting handle is set
    // If it doesn't the thread will be aborted if it takes longer than abortTimeout
    protected abstract void WorkUnit(WaitHandle exiting);

    // override if you need to cleanup on exit
    protected virtual void ThreadCleanup() { }
}
```

Which gives your thread a chance to exit gracefully and only aborts if a graceful exit fails.

Comment: You don't want to put very long running operations in thread pool threas.  You should just mark the thread you create as a background thread through `IsBackground = true` instead.

Comment: so with the example in the website I mentioned, how do I close the 2 threads properly?  =/

Answer (score 0):

OK,
found my answer.  I gotta declare the threads so that references can be made to them.  then, I end the nested thread (which has HandleClientComm()) first, then close the TCP_Client (if not null) and the TCP_Listener.  then I end the ListenThread().  also, the TCP_Listener.Pending() method mentioned here [Proper way to stop TcpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365370/proper-way-to-stop-tcplistener) must be implemented.